# Does Sinatra have a logger like in Rails?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'd like to have a simple logger as I have in Rails.
Just to log all requests with all their parameters.
Can's figure out how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: @nyzm I don't think so -- this asker is only looking to log requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
configure do
  class ::Logger; alias_method :write, :<<; end
  use Rack::CommonLogger, Logger.new('logs/app.log')
end
```

taken from here: [customink/stoplight](https://github.com/customink/stoplight/issues/14)

Comment: This monkey-patch seems unnecessary. Have you tried subclassing Logger?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
configure do
  enable :logging
end
```

See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Logging

Comment: That didn't really help...

Comment: As far as I can see, the only difference between mine and yours is that mine writes to stdout and yours writes to a file called log/app.log. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know, may be my configuration is a bit different, so I was need to add thei workaround.